# How to handle responsive images with vertical rhythm?

Tags: html, css, compass, typography

I'm developing an HTML page using Compass/SCSS and a vertical rhythm approach. I've set up a baseline and specified heights for paragraphs and headings in rem units. It works great and lays on a vertical rhythm grid nicely. However, I have a central image that takes 100% width of the column (I want it to be responsive and scale with the browser window).

The problem is that this image breaks vertical rhythm because it's height is calculated dynamically according to the browser width and image aspect ratio and is not respecting the baseline.

How do I handle this situation in order to have a perfect vertical rhythm?

---

Here's the screenshot to demonstrate the idea:

[image]

---

As you can see the text below the image breaks out of the VR grid.

I've tried to use [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) jQuery plugin, but looks like it's outdated and is not working correctly.

Comment: any code and css used to show your dilema ? fake text and image is fine within aa codepen or jsfiddle ;)

Comment: Vertical rhythm is a goal....perfection is unlikely.

Comment: You could place the image in a container and give that container a fixed height and overflow: hidden; that way, the bottom 5-6 pixels of the image will be cut out realigning your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Library

Me and my colleague have created a library that solves this problem almost ideally with minimal image distortions.

Feel free to look into it, test it and use in your projects:
https://github.com/betsol/baseline-element

---

## Prior conceptual solution

Here's the conceptual solution I've came up with in the end:

```js
$(function () {

  var baseline = 24;

  var $image = $('#sample-image');
  var imageAspectRatio = ($image.width() / $image.height());

  wrapImage($image);

  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeImage);
  resizeImage();

  function wrapImage ($image) {
    var $wrap = $('<div class="image-wrap">')
      .css('overflow', 'hidden')
    ;
    $image
      .css('width', 'auto')
      .css('display', 'block')
    ;
    $image.after($wrap);
    $wrap.append($image);
  }

  function resizeImage () {
    var newHeight = ($image.parent().width() / imageAspectRatio);
    var leftover = (newHeight % baseline);
    $image.css('height', newHeight + (baseline - leftover));
  }

});
```

It dynamically creates a container around image, set's image width to auto and uses `resize` event to manually calculate the image height with respect to baseline. That way image will be slightly cut by the right border, but it should work.

---

And here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have made a plugin for this case. Please check it out.

Now available in npm, run `npm install jquery-rhythmplease` to install.

Please feel free to leave any kind of feedback.

The plugin does not change the aspect ratio of the image.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.rhythm-please').on('load', function() {
    $(this).rhythmPlease();
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, transparent 26px, rgba(0, 173, 240, 0.1) 27px, rgba(0, 173, 240, 0.1));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 26px, rgba(0, 173, 240, 0.1) 27px, rgba(0, 173, 240, 0.1));
  background-size: 100% 28px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/halfzebra/jquery-rhythmplease/master/src/jquery.rhythmPlease.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p class="text">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
      <img class="rhythm-please" src="http://placehold.it/350x230">
      <p class="text">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p class="text">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img class="rhythm-please" src="http://placehold.it/500x690">
      <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12"><span class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's cool. Thanks! Why don't you put it on GitHub and Bower/npm? I would be glad to try it.

Comment: @SlavaFominII you can get the source by running `npm install jquery-rhythmplease`, thanks for a good suggestion!